# Symbian: Is it possible to get access to a list of contacts through an application?

Tags: c++, java-me, mobile, symbian, nokia

There are at least two ways that I know of to write a Symbian application:
1.  J2ME
2.  A native application.

My question is, does the SDK/API for either of those methods (or any other method) grant me (at least) read-only access to contact information (names/numbers/etc) on the phone itself?  Does this in any way depend on the specific phone being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, you can use e.g. the Contacts Model API. There's an [example](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/604e40f2-a85c-4a16-8699-0f34a85b0b14/S60_Platform_Contacts_Model_API_Example.html) in Forum Nokia.

In J2ME, you need to be working on [a phone that has JSR-75](http://www.forum.nokia.com/advanced-search/search.xhtml?mandatoryKeywords=&facets=&keywords=&resourceType=http%3A%2F%2Fsw.nokia.com%2FFN-1%2FType%2FTerminal&searchSubmitted=true&mandatoryFacets=UEsDBBQACAAIAERmyzoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAMKvIKCkpSDW1cE01MQfj4vJUEzPXvPzszEQQIzk%2FFyxjZuEakGpi6moI4mUlliWmWpq6JhZkRoRWkGOCF9AExwBPsGHFReamEQpEGuPmBzejpLIg1dDA0JVoJyDpDYHqBbPBrKLczLzEnAgFAFBLBwhJMi25bAAAABEBAAA%3D&editorView=http%3A%2F%2Fsw.nokia.com%2FEditor-1%2FView%2Fsearch). Again, there's an [example](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_read_contacts_using_JSR_75) in Forum Nokia.

Comment: Thanks - what % of the existing Nokia smartphones is this available for?  The Contacts Model API looks like it's S60 only, and JSR-75 looks like it's for PDAs.  

Are these technologies also applicable for lower-end/older nokia phones?

Comment: You asked specifically about Symbian :-)
All Nokia Smartphones are S60 apart from a few legacy ones on S80, they're all Symbian anyway and the Contacts Model is there.
JSR-75 has two components, File Connection and PIM access.  Unfortunately I think the latter part is relatively rare on low-end devices.

Comment: @AlexeyMK: The Contacts Model API is a Symbian API so it is not restricted to S60 only. JSR-75 is supported on practically all recent devices. I'll add details to my answer, the URL is practically too long to include here.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I should have been specific - I'm interested in specifically lower-end devices such as those most in use in the developing world - India, CIS states, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Open the default contact database using CContactDatabase::OpenL(). use thus returned database object in TContactIter::NextL() in a loop to fetch the IDs of every contact in the contact book.

Comment: Dude try adding some more detail to your answer. It would really help others too

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget, as well as native C++ and J2ME (MIDP), you have:

- Python ([Example of Contacts access](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Search_in_contacts))
- Flash Lite ([Example of contacts access](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/CS001223_-_Listing_contacts_in_Flash_Lite))
- Widgets ([Example of contacts access](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/CS001235_-_Retrieving_contacts_info_in_WRT))

If you are thinking about lower-end devices which are often S40 devices, MIDP is probably your best bet however.